# Does this sigma function correspond to this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm kind of self-taught in sigmas, and I'm not very proficient in calculus nor precalculus. Therefore, I'd like to see if the series I've thought of does correspond to this sigma function

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\times\frac k2$$

Corresponds to this series:

$$1\times\frac 12+2\times \frac 22+3\times \frac 32 + 4\times\frac 42 ... n\times\frac n2$$

I'm wondering because I want to do a little recreational study of this series, and see if what kind of relations *n* has to the sums. To do that, it would be nice to compress that series to a sigma function, and I'm wondering if I did it correctly here.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$?

Comment: The Sigma isn't a function (at least not in the usual sense). Other than that your reasoning is correct, and it is in fact true that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\cdot k}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$$

Comment: @K.defaoite I may have to update what my understanding of a function is. I didn't think it required an equal sign. Is $$\frac {k\times k} 2$$ the same as $$k \times \frac k2$$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite My formatting is wrong can't get it to work. The mangled fraction is supposed to be the fraction you had. EDIT: I've fixed it now.

Comment: Multiplication of real numbers is commutative, so yes.

Comment: Don't know what that is, but checked on a calculator and now I've learned something new :) @K.defaoite But, for my function to be a function, I must show what its sum will be?

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, my calculations were wrong. Interesting to see that these two sigma functions equal the same sum.

Comment: You can always pull a multiplicative constant out of a sum.  It's just the distributive law of multiplication over addition.

Comment: Haven't heard of this law @saulspatz I'll check into it. This revelation that $$\frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k\times \frac k2$$ is actually very relevant to some recreational math I'm doing. If I can find a process to turn the first sigma notation into the second (or vice verca), then I think that can be used a proof, or part of one, for an equation that is for the moment simply a conjecture. Interesting stuff this.

Comment: The distributive law simply says that $a(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n)=ab_1+ab_2+\cdots+ab_n$ which is to say $$a\sum_{k=1}^nb_k=\sum_{k=1}^nab_k$$

Comment: Oh wow, of course. That crystallized it @saulspatz Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Adding this as an answer to avoid excessive comments.

First point:

Yes, it is true that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\times\frac{k}{2}=1\times\frac{1}{2}+2\times\frac{2}{2}+...+n\times\frac{n}{2}$$
**PROOF:** Um... plug the numbers in. The way Sigma notation works is that
$$\sum_{k=m}^n f(k)=f(m)+f(m+1)+...+f(n-1)+f(n)$$
But we can extend this to non-indexed sets (as long as they are countable), e.g
$$\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}f(x)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)+...~~\forall x_i\in\mathcal{X}.$$

Second Point:

Notice that I am calling this "Sigma *notation*" not a "Sigma *function*" as it really is just a way of writing things to make it shorter. You could, very formally, think of this instead as a map ("function") that takes in two inputs - another function, and a set:
$$\Sigma(f,S)=f(s_1)+f(s_2)+f(s_3)+...~~\forall s_i\in S$$
E.g,
$$\Sigma(\text{id},\mathbb{N}_{\leq m})=\sum_{k=1}^m k=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$
But this is frankly overkill and unnecessarily complicates a simple idea.

Third point:

Yes, it is true that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\times\frac{k}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k\times k}{2}$$
There is nothing special about this! In a very crude manner, you can just "cancel out" the summation signs on both sides to get
$$k\times \frac{k}{2}=\frac{k\times k}{2}$$
Which is obviously true, e.g $(6\times 6)/2=36/2=18$ and $6\times (6/2)=6\times 3=18.$